# C++ displaying array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

Hi when running this small program, I appear to have an output of the memory addresses rather than the values stored inside them: any  ideas? thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[5] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    int b[5] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
    int c[10] = {};
    int j, i;

    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (a[j] < b[j])
        {
            c[j] = a[j];
        }

        else
        {
            c[j] = b[j];
        }
    }

    for (i= 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << c[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note the first loop could just be a `std::transform` call (which would immediately get rid of the bug you have there). If you're going for a merge type thing, use `std::merge` instead.

Comment: First of all, you're iterating past the size of arrays a and b, hence you've got undefined behavior, and strange numbers. Correct your first 'if' and then return back with question (if needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditions are wrong. `a` and `b` both have size `5`, but you are iterating upto `size` 10.

Comment: -facepalm- embarrassing lol thank you I changed the first "for loops" iteration to 5and now it works.